# Telegram bot doesn't send messages to discord channel

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I've tried creating a Discord bot that sends my messages to a Telegram group. Later on, I attempted to integrate the reverse process. From what I've seen, the dispatcher function has been modified, so I tried with 'application.' However, it still doesn't work. Any help?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import telegram
from telegram import Bot as TelegramBot
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Application, ContextTypes



discord_token = '000'
telegram_token = '000'

updater = Application.builder().token(telegram_token).build()

intents = discord.Intents.all()  
intents.typing = False  
intents.messages = True  
intents.guild_messages = True  




async def get_chat_id():
    bot = TelegramBot(token=telegram_token)
    updates = await bot.get_updates(timeout=10)  
    if updates:
        chat_id = updates[-1].message.chat_id
        return chat_id
    else:
        return None



async def send_to_telegram(text, user):
    chat_id = await get_chat_id()
    content=f"{user}: {text}"
    if chat_id:
        try:
            telegram_bot = TelegramBot(token=telegram_token)
            await telegram_bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=content)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Errore nell'invio del messaggio a Telegram: {e}")
    else:
        print("Impossibile ottenere il chat_id del gruppo Telegram.")



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Connesso come {bot.user.name}')
    channel_id = await get_chat_id()
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)

    if channel:
        await channel.send("Sono online e pronto ad agire!")
    else:
        print("Canale non trovato. Assicurati di avere inserito un ID di canale valido.")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != bot.user:
        print(message.author)
        user=message.author
        print(f"Messaggio ricevuto: {message}")
        print(f"Contenuto del messaggio ricevuto: {message.clean_content}")
        content=message.content
        if content[:8]!="Telegram":
            await send_to_telegram(message.content, user)
          


async def send_to_discord(update: telegram.Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user = update.message.from_user
    content = update.message.text

    print(f"Messaggio ricevuto: {content}")

    channel_id = await get_chat_id() 
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)

    if channel:
        await channel.send(f"Telegram: {user['username']}#{user['id']}: {content}")
    else:
        print("Canale non trovato. Assicurati di avere inserito un ID di canale valido.")


updater.add_handler(MessageHandler(None, send_to_discord))

bot.run(discord_token)
updater.run_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Any ideas? i've already tried reading documentetion